# How to determine the regression line for the data points(Theory)?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

Determine the regression line for the below data points:

```
(x1, y1) = (1, 4), (x2, y2) = (2, 3), (x3, y3) = (3, 9)
```

i.e. the `function h(x) = w + hx` that minimizes the squared error loss on this data.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question; see  [ask].

Comment: Please don't ask this kind of questions, as they are off-topic in Stack Overflow. Only programming questions are allowed here.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ may be the place to go, though the question needs some work, see Marks comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question just boils down to math.

First, we write our error function

[image]

The derivative of the error function tells us how the error changes as we change variables.  Because there are two variables (m and b), it is a partial derivative.  When the derivative is equal to zero we know we have reached a minimum (and because we're taking the derivative of a quadratic we know there is a single global minimum).

[image]

Writing out each term in the sum gives us

[image]

Two variables, two equations means we can solve for both!

[image]

In your case we have h=m and w=b

As a double check, Desmos is a great tool https://www.desmos.com/calculator

[image]